# How to get AucTex to prompt me for a name, when inserting an environment using Ctrl-C, Ctrl-E?

Tags: environments, templates, emacs, auctex

I'm using emacs auctex. I've defined an environment template, as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I insert instances of this environment into the document using the `Ctrl-C, Ctrl-E` keyboard shortcut. Upon doing so, I'd like to be prompted for a name, which will be included in square brackets thus:

```
\begin{definition}[Cauchy-Schwartz]
\end{definition}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you want to do it for every new theorem defined with `\newtheorem` or just for the `definition` environment?  The latter case is much easier.

Comment: @giordano: Selected theorems defined with `\newtheorem` (some yes, some no).

Answer (score 3):

The solution I'm going to provide requires parsing of files enabled.  As explained in the [AUCTeX manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Parsing-Files) you can achieve it by adding this to your `.emacs`, if you haven't already done that

```lisp
(setq TeX-parse-self t) ; Enable parse on load.
(setq TeX-auto-save t) ; Enable parse on save.
```

In addition I remind you that it's advisable to add also the line

```lisp
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
```

in order to manage multi-file documents.

Returning to your question, add the following code to your `.emacs` (this should work also with the current stable version of AUCTeX, 11.87)

```lisp
(add-hook
 'LaTeX-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (TeX-auto-add-type "theorem" "mg-LaTeX")
   ;; Self Parsing -- see (info "(auctex)Hacking the Parser").
   (defvar mg-LaTeX-theorem-regexp
     (concat "\\\\newtheorem{\\(" TeX-token-char "+\\)}")
     "Matches new theorems.")
   (defvar mg-LaTeX-auto-theorem nil
     "Temporary for parsing theorems.")
   (defun mg-LaTeX-theorem-prepare ()
     "Clear `mg-LaTex-auto-theorem' before use."
     (setq mg-LaTeX-auto-theorem nil))
   (defun mg-LaTeX-theorem-cleanup ()
     "Move theorems from `mg-LaTeX-auto-theorem' to `mg-LaTeX-theorem-list'.
Add theorem to the environment list with an optional argument."
     (mapcar (lambda (theorem)
           (add-to-list 'mg-LaTeX-theorem-list (list theorem))
           (LaTeX-add-environments
        `(,theorem ["Name"])))
         mg-LaTeX-auto-theorem))
   ;; FIXME: This does not seem to work unless one does a manual reparse.
   (add-hook 'TeX-auto-prepare-hook 'mg-LaTeX-theorem-prepare)
   (add-hook 'TeX-auto-cleanup-hook 'mg-LaTeX-theorem-cleanup)
   (TeX-auto-add-regexp `(,mg-LaTeX-theorem-regexp 1 mg-LaTeX-auto-theorem))))
```

After this edit, restart Emacs (note: usually a <kbd>M-x</kbd> `eval-buffer` <kbd>RET</kbd>, but by restarting Emacs you'll be sure the changes will be loaded correctly).  Open a document with a `\newtheorem` definition, (re)parse the file, e.g. do a dummy edit (and and delete a space) and save the buffer, then you'll be able to add your theorems with an optional `Name` argument.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. I use Emacs 24.3.1

Comment: @EvanAad  Ok, but what's your AUCTeX version?  Anyway, due to internal limitations of AUCTeX (mentioned in the comments to the code), you have first to (re)parse the file, e.g. do a dummy edit, save the buffer and then you'll be able to add your theorems with an optional argument.

Comment: I've followed your instruction (i.e. did a dummy edit and saved the buffer), but still, it doesn't work. My AUCTex version is 11.87.2012-12-04.

Comment: @EvanAad  That's strange: I've just tested the code with AUCTeX 11.87 and it should work.  I always give it for granted, but have you enabled parsing of files?

Comment: I don't know what "enabled parsing of files" means, or how to do it.

Comment: @EvanAad I added the explanation in the updated answer `;-)`.

Comment: I have added the parsing directives to .emacs, but to no avail. Maybe I don't understand the way your code is supposed to be invoked. How am I supposed to use it from within emacs?

Comment: @EvanAad I added a little more information.  I hope this helps `:-)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It doesn't work for me, but I really appreciate your help. I'll just do without this feature for the time being.

Comment: @EvanAad  I'm so sorry I didn't manage to help you `:-(`